Webhook validation handshake failed with response code unknown
I'm unable to update the webhook endpoint of Event grid subscription. I've created a new http triggered azure function and I'm trying to update the webhook endpoint point of an event subscription to this new function.
After update the endpoint and adding x-function-key in Header in Delivery Properties, I'm getting an error while saving it saying:
Deployment has failed with the following error: {"code":"URL validation","message":"Webhook validation handshake failed for https://eventgridl3functionapp.azurewebsites.net/api/eventgridl3functionapp. Http POST request failed with response code Unknown. For troubleshooting, visit https://aka.ms/esvalidation. Activity id:5dae7825-6144-4d9d-8adf-3b764bb6a7f7, timestamp: 8/8/2024 5:22:40 AM (UTC)."}
Could anyone assist me in debugging this?
I was able to update the event subscription webbook endpoint few days back and then I updated the http trigger function (removed some unnecessary logs from there) and now I'm unable to update the endpoint. Can I find specific error using the Activity Id?

You can get the function URL and use that.

Not sure if it's related but found this in application insights traces and exception -
"Category":"Function.EventGridL3FunctionApp","HostInstanceId":"aa480e87-5e33-498e-ae82-c36aec5c20f5","LogLevel":"Error","prop__{OriginalFormat}":"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'EventGridL3FunctionApp'. System.Private.CoreLib: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Linq.Expressions, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified."

@Prashant Verma what is the authorization level set in your http trigger?

Authorization Level is set as Function

@Prashant Verma You need to ?code=<access key>in your url. You can also copy the URL from your function fromget function url image

Tried it.. Didn't work either. Same error

@PrashantVerma In function app get the master key from access keys in left options and use that in the ?code= value

Tried that as well. Didn't work

@PrashantVerma As mentioned in this MS Doc, the Webhook mode was only available for version 1.x of the Functions runtime but we now using version 4.x. So, it's not possible to configure the Webhook with the Azure function app endpoint.

@PrashantVerma If you want to trigger the function with the Event grid, an Event grid trigger in the function is available. You can use that.

To trigger events using Azure Functions without relying on a Webhook, you can follow the process described below. This method uses an EventGridTrigger to listen for events from Azure Event Grid, allowing you to handle events directly within your Azure Function.
Code :
using Azure.Messaging.EventGrid;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp2
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;

        public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [Function(nameof(Function1))]
        public void Run([EventGridTrigger] EventGridEvent cloudEvent)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Event type: {type}, Event subject: {subject}", cloudEvent.EventType, cloudEvent.Subject);
        }
    }
}

I published the EventGrid trigger function code to the AZure Function app as shown below,

Postman :
https://<Eventgridtopic_name>.eastus-1.eventgrid.azure.net/api/events

json data :
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "topic": "",
        "subject": "sampletest",
        "eventType": "function",
        "eventTime": "2024-01-06T12:00:00Z",
        "data": {
            "Name": "Kamali"
        }
    }
]

In the Headers, replace your access key as shown below,
aeg-sas-key = replace your EventGridTopic acces key


After adding the Headers and raw json body, you can use the Post reqest method to send the events to the Azure Function app.

Function app Logs in Invocations :


Thanks @Dasari Kamali for this approach! Will look into EventGridTrigger as well.
